# why nginx close upstream keepalive connection when user cancel request

Tags: nginx, grpc

in my case, i use keepalive params to keepalive the upstream. and i use nginx for grpc balancing.

```
upstream grpc_servers {
server  ${GRPC_PROXY};
keepalive_timeout 65s;
keepalive 1000;
keepalive_requests 1000;
}
```

the http section is

```
http {
    proxy_connect_timeout  30s;
    proxy_send_timeout  30s;
    proxy_read_timeout  30s;
    client_header_timeout 15s;
    client_body_timeout 15s;
    keepalive_timeout  120s 120s;
    keepalive_requests 1000;
    send_timeout 15s;
    proxy_ignore_client_abort on;
    include '/etc/nginx/conf.d/backend.conf';
}
```

but when i test the long time request, the user cancel the request. i found nginx also close the upstream keepalive connection
the nginx log is below

```
2022/03/15 13:14:45 [debug] 1630#1630: *108704 http2 read handler                                                                                                                        
2022/03/15 13:14:45 [debug] 1630#1630: *108704 SSL_read: 0                                                                                                                               
2022/03/15 13:14:45 [debug] 1630#1630: *108704 SSL_get_error: 5                                                                                                                          
2022/03/15 13:14:45 [debug] 1630#1630: *108704 peer shutdown SSL cleanly                                                                                                                 
2022/03/15 13:14:45 [info] 1630#1630: *108704 client prematurely closed connection while processing HTTP/2 connection, client: 172.30.0.7, server: 0.0.0.0:9081                          
2022/03/15 13:14:45 [debug] 1630#1630: *108704 http run request: "/config.Config/DelayTest?"                                                                                             
2022/03/15 13:14:45 [debug] 1630#1630: *108704 http upstream check client, write event:0, "/config.Config/DelayTest"                                                                     
2022/03/15 13:14:45 [debug] 1630#1630: *108704 finalize http upstream request: 499                                                                                                       
2022/03/15 13:14:45 [debug] 1630#1630: *108704 finalize grpc request                                                                                                                     
2022/03/15 13:14:45 [debug] 1630#1630: *108704 free keepalive peer                                                                                                                       
2022/03/15 13:14:45 [debug] 1630#1630: *108704 free rr peer 1 0                                                                                                                          
2022/03/15 13:14:45 [debug] 1630#1630: *108704 close http upstream connection: 13                                                                                                        
2022/03/15 13:14:45 [debug] 1630#1630: *108704 run cleanup: 00007FE60F969D50                                                                                                             
2022/03/15 13:14:45 [debug] 1630#1630: *108704 free: 00007FE60F969D00, unused: 24                                                                                                        
2022/03/15 13:14:45 [debug] 1630#1630: *108704 free: 00007FE60F969640, unused: 64                                                                                                        
2022/03/15 13:14:45 [debug] 1630#1630: *108704 event timer del: 13: 1146016191                                                                                                           
2022/03/15 13:14:45 [debug] 1630#1630: *108704 reusable connection: 0                                                                                                                    
2022/03/15 13:14:45 [debug] 1630#1630: *108704 http finalize request: 499, "/config.Config/DelayTest?" a:1, c:1                                                                          
2022/03/15 13:14:45 [debug] 1630#1630: *108704 http terminate request count:1                                                                                                            
2022/03/15 13:14:45 [debug] 1630#1630: *108704 http terminate cleanup count:1 blk:0                                                                                                      
2022/03/15 13:14:45 [debug] 1630#1630: *108704 http posted request: "/config.Config/DelayTest?"                                                                                          
2022/03/15 13:14:45 [debug] 1630#1630: *108704 http terminate handler count:1                                                                                                            
2022/03/15 13:14:45 [debug] 1630#1630: *108704 http request count:1 blk:0                                                                                                                
2022/03/15 13:14:45 [debug] 1630#1630: *108704 http2 close stream 1, queued 0, processing 1, pushing 0                                                                                   
2022/03/15 13:14:45 [debug] 1630#1630: *108704 http close request                                                                                                                        
2022/03/15 13:14:45 [debug] 1630#1630: *108704 http log handler
```

i want to know if is there any way to keepalive the upstream even user close client connection?